# Intel® Wireless 7265D: iw shows wrong regulatory information

Tags: wifi, iwlwifi

On a computer with the Intel® 7265D wifi device `iw reg get` produces the following output:

```
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)


phy#0 (self-managed)
country DE: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, GO-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5815 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, GO-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5815 - 5835 @ 20), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, GO-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
```

According to the output the wifi card seems to manage the regulatory domain itself.
The set country `DE` is correct, but the information on the used frequencies and txpowers do not match the regulations for `DE`.
On a another computer with a Intel® 7260 I get the following output and this is what I expect.

```
country DE: DFS-ETSI
   (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
   (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
   (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
   (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
   (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

This is the list I expect from reading the `wireless-regdb` (see http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/sforshee/wireless-regdb.git/tree/db.txt).

The problematic output for the 7265 was produced on computer running openSUSE Leap 42.1.
The `crda` version is `3.18-5.1` and the version of `wireless-regdb` is `2015.07.20-1.1`. Thus outdated versions cannot be the reason for this problem.

My guess is, that the output of `iw reg get` is not correct for self-managed devices. This would explain the correct information in case of the 7260 module. According to `iw` this is not self-managed.

Thank you very much.

P.S.: some information on the 7265D module

```
[...]loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[...]Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to disable the LAR functionality, so it won't appear as a "self-manged" device anymore. Then You can set the regulatory domain with `iw reg set`. All you need to do is setting the iwlwifi parameter `lar_disable=1`:

1. Either manually: `modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi lar_disable=1`
2. Automatically: `echo options iwlwifi lar_disable=1 >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want to change the regulatory domain. I just did not know how to interpret the output of iw reg get in this case. In my opinion it would be cool if iw would be able to display the regulatory domain which was chosen by the firmware of the wifi card in the case of self-managed devices.